# Custom widget cannot be cast to custom widget

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-widget

I created a custom widget extending `EditText` that looks like an `EditText` but acts a little different, this is the code, although I don't think the content of that class is the problem:

```
public class SalutationEditTextLikeButton extends EditText {

    CharSequence[] options;
    String selection;
    Context context;

    long performClickCatch = 0;

    public void dontPerformClickForMilliseconds(long milliseconds) {
        performClickCatch = System.currentTimeMillis() + milliseconds;
    }

    public SalutationEditTextLikeButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        disableInput();
    }

    public SalutationEditTextLikeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        this.context = context;
        disableInput();

    }

    public SalutationEditTextLikeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        disableInput();
    }

    private void disableInput() {
        this.setCursorVisible(false);
        setKeyListener(null);
    }

    public String getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(String selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
        this.setHint("");
        this.setText(selection);
        this.clearComposingText();

    }

    public void setOptions(CharSequence[] options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Log.d("butx", "save");

        return super.onSaveInstanceState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() < performClickCatch) {
            return true;
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.anrede));

        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                setSelection(options[which].toString());
                setError(null);
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        this.clearComposingText();

        return true;

    }
}
```

I use this class like this:

```
final SalutationEditTextLikeButton salutationEditTextLikeButton
        = (SalutationEditTextLikeButton) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_salutationbutton_w_style, null);
```

with the xml layout being:

```
<xy.SalutationEditTextLikeButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

At the line

```
final SalutationEditTextLikeButton salutationEditTextLikeButton
        = (SalutationEditTextLikeButton) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_salutationbutton_w_style, null);
```

I get a rare exception report on Crittercism with the following exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
xy.SalutationEditTextLikeButton cannot be cast to xy.SalutationEditTextLikeButton
```

which seems very odd to me. A had the same exception occasionally with other custom widgets.

This one only occurs on Samsung's Galaxy S5 (SM-G900F).

Any ideas on what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: You've likely got a duplicate copy of SalutationEditTextLikeButton.java ?

Answer (score 1):

First try to give id to ur custom view :

```
<xy.SalutationEditTextLikeButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/salutationEditTextLikeButton"
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now inflate xml  :

```
final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_salutationbutton_w_style, null);
```

Cast ur custom view from layout inflator reference using custom view xml id :

```
final SalutationEditTextLikeButton salutationEditTextLikeButton = (SalutationEditTextLikeButton) view.findViewById(R.id.salutationEditTextLikeButton);
```

Comment: Will this work If the `SalutationEditTextLikeButton` is the parent view in `single_salutationbutton_w_style.xml` ?

Comment: Yes but have to required id in xml for SalutationEditTextLikeButton .

Comment: From `View.findViewById()` Source code, Yes it will work (return the `View`). but in his case from the Crash log you can see that he got the correct `View` `xy.SalutationEditTextLikeButton cannot be cast to xy.SalutationEditTextLikeButton`. So I think this will not solve the problem.